# Nova Launcher Google search bar

Tags: google

I just upgraded phone and reinstalled Nova Launcher. I inadvertently deleted the single page, customizable search bar on my home page. I don't want a persistent search bar. I can't get a single, customizable bar on my home page. I can add a single bar as a widget but it doesn't customize when I try and change the settings in Nova. Or I can add a customized but PERSISTENT search bar thru Nova. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Nova settings only allow for a persistent search bar, from what I can tell....If I understand correctly, you just want the search bar on your main home screen?

Comment: Did you mean Google search widget?

Answer (score 3):

Add a search bar widget, but don't use the one supplied by Google Search (which is fixed-style) - instead, Nova itself offers the customizable one you're looking for, under Nova Launcher - Quick Search Bar.

[image]

This search bar shares its customization options with the persistent one, under Nova Settings - Desktop - Search bar.

[image]